# How to check machine learning accuracy without cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, random-forest

I have training sample `X_train`, and `Y_train` to train and `X_estimated`.
I got task to make my classificator learn as accurate as it can, and then predict vector of results over `X_estimated` to get close results to `Y_estimated` (which i have now, and I have to be as much precise as it can). If I split my training data to like 75/25 to train and test it, I can get accuracy using `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score` and confusion matrix. But I am losing that 25% of samples, that would make my predictions more accurate.

Is there any way, I could learn by using 100% of the data, and still be able to see accuracy score (or percentage), so I can predict it many times, and save best (%) result?
I am using random forest with 500 estimators, and usually get like 90% accuracy. I want to save best prediction vector as possible for my task, without splitting any data (not wasting anything), but still be able to calculate accuracy (so I can save best prediction vector) from multiple attempts (random forest always shows different results)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting your data is critical for evaluation. 
There is no way that you could train your model on 100% of the data and be able to get a correct evaluation accuracy unless you expand your dataset. I mean, you could change your train/test split, or try to optimize your model in other ways, but i guess the simple answer to your question would be no.

Comment: I understand. Can I ask then, is it better to split data, train them, see accuracy and with that trained classifier predict Y_estimated. Or train them with 100% sample and predict Y_estimated? What would eventually be more accurate?

Comment: @victory, those are not really comparable. For reliable accuracy statistics, you need to reserve a little bit of the dataset. Evaluation and prediction are very similar, evaluation compares the generated label to the real one while prediction tells you the label it thinks it is. Predicting labels when not reserving part of the dataset as test will not give you a correct answer or at least not a useful one. The whole point of machine learning is that the computer can train on one set and identify **another**. You always need to reserve a little bit of your data to test on or predict later.

Comment: The very point of building a model is that it generalises well. Typically you use 3 sets: training, dev and test (terminology varies). Dev set is used to tune hyperparameters while test to report your metrics. It needs to be "large enough" to represent well general population. If you say "but then I don't have enough training data!", maybe ML is not a good option and some heuristics should be used. Or you should use weakly supervised models. Or less "data hungry" algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

As per your requirement, you can try [K Fold Cross Validation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/). If you split it in 90|10 i.e for Train|Test. 
 Achieving to take 100% data for training is not possible as you have to test the data then only you can validate the same that how good your model is. K Fold CV takes your whole train data into consideration in each fold and randomly takes test data sample from the train data.
 And lastly calculates the accuracy by taking summation of all the folds. Then finally you can test the accuracy by using 10% of the data.
More you can read [here](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/k-fold-cross-validation-6b8518070833) and [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/05/improve-model-performance-cross-validation-in-python-r/)

> **K Fold Cross Validation**

[image]

Skearn provides simple methods for performing K fold cross validation. Simply you have to pass no of folds in the method. But then remember, more the folds, it takes more time to train the model. More you can check [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to do 75|25 split of your data all the time. 75
|25 is kind of old school now. It greatly depends on the amount of data that you have. For example, if you have 1 billion sentences for training a language model, it is not necessary to reserve 25% for testing.

Also, I second the previous answer of trying K-fold cross-validation. As a side note, you could consider looking at the other metrics like precision and recall as well.

Answer (score 0):

In general **splitting your data set is critical for evaluation**. So I would recommend you **always** do that.

Said that, there are methods that in some sense allow you to train on all your data and still get an estimate of your performance or to estimate the generalization accuracy.
One particularly prominent method is leveraging out-of-bag samples of models based on bootstrapping, i.e. RandomForests.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, bootstrap=True, oob_score=True)
rf.fit(X, y)
print(rf.oob_score_)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing classification always go with stratified k-fold cv(https://machinelearningmastery.com/cross-validation-for-imbalanced-classification/).
if you're doing regression then go with simple k-fold cv or you can divide the target as bins and do stratified k-fold cv. by this way you can use your data completely in model training.